Using で to mark location with いる?
In this audio practice (at 1:36) to accompany the Genki textbooks, the native Japanese speaker says:
ニュージーランドで　日本人の　友達が　いました。 I had a Japanese friend in New Zealand.
What's the nuance of using で to mark location with いる, instead of the typical に?  I know で can mark location with ある sometimes, but doing the same with いる seems quite rare, and quite obtuse for beginner-level content.
